# How to position an image between JQuery connectedSortable containers

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got an HTML page with two unordered lists, of type connectedSortable.  I'd like to put an arrow image in between the containers, to indicate that items should be dragged from one to the other.

The css for my arrow container looks like this:

```
.centered_invisible
{
  position: relative;
  float: center;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<ul name="dragSrc" id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable" >
  <li value="foo" class="ui-state-default">Item</li>
</ul>
<div class="centered_invisible"><img src="images/RightGreenArrow.png" height="50" width="100"></div>
<ul name="dragDst" id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable" >
</ul>
```

The arrow displays correctly, but it always appears **on top of** the right-hand container.  I want it to appear in between the containers (centered, ideally).  Is there a way to do that with either css or HTML?  I've tried padding and JQuery's "after" function, but so far I can't get the arrow to go between the containers.

Comment: You should post the entire relevant css code for us to replicate the issue. Better yet prepare a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it - set a static height to your lists (+ `overflow-y` to scroll), then set `margin-top` of the arrow to `half of the list height - half of your image height`.

For example:

**HTML**

```
<ul name="dragSrc" id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li value="foo" class="ui-state-default">Item</li>
</ul>
<div class="centered_invisible"><img src="images/RightGreenArrow.png" height="50" width="100"></div>
<ul name="dragDst" id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li value="foo" class="ui-state-default">Item</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.connectedSortable {
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#sortable2 {
  text-align: right;
}

.centered_invisible {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 125px;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/hdsvqq15/)

You can play around with the formatting - the border is just to show the bounding box.

Answer (score 0):

The property **center** with float does not exists, you have to replace it with the **text-align** property:

The **margin** attribute with auto is useless in this case, you can use the statement when you use **position : absolute**;

```css
.centered_invisible
{
  position: relative;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<ul name="dragSrc" id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable" >
  <li value="foo" class="ui-state-default">Item</li>
</ul>
<div class="centered_invisible"><img src="images/RightGreenArrow.png" height="50" width="100"></div>
<ul name="dragDst" id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable" >
</ul>
```